# Creating an executable installer in Java

Tags: java, installation, windows-installer

I am interested in making a one-click installer for my C# application.

I had the the framework of the application down. The logic of the application in the installer() method was:

```
public static void installer(){
        deleteLegacyFiles(); // deletes old files through a find method
        moveSQLite(); // moves the database file
        if(checkRevit2013()){ // checks whether Revit '13 is installed
            movePlugin2013(); // moves my plugin into the Addin folder or Revit
        }else if(checkRevit2014()){ // check whether Revit '14 is installed
            movePlugin2014(); // moves my plugin into the Addin folder or Revit
        }else{ 
            System.out.println("It does not look like you have either Revit 2013 or Revit 2014 installed.");
        }
    }
```

However, this Java script (not Javascript, but a Java script) really only took three folders from the `/Desktop/` and copies them to their respective `target` folders. I am interested in a solution that turns all my three folders into one executable file (something like an `.exe` or `.msi`) and do the above actions.

Are there any solutions for this for Java? Something that packages multiple folders/files together and then allows for one-click solutions for installation? I'm not exactly how to phrase what I want, as this is my first software development project. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for making/building an executable jar file? If so you can use something like one-jar.

http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=introduction&file=intro

Here are the steps:

1. Create an executable JAR file with your application's CLASS files in it. (Navigate to bin directory of workspace) Name this "main.jar"
                   jar cfm main.jar manifest.txt *.class OR [jar cfm main.jar manifest.txt *.*]
2. Create three directories: MAIN, LIB, and BOOT
3. Place your "main.jar" file in the MAIN directory.
4. Place the jar files that your main application depends on in the LIB directory.
5. Naigate to Packaging- Create a new JAR file out of the MAIN and LIB directories. Name this one "MyUtil.jar". You do not need to add a manifest or do anything special to this file. It does not need to be executable. Just make it so that it contains the contents of the MAIN and LIB directories. 
          jar cf MyUtil.jar main lib
6. Extract the contents of the "one-jar-boot.jar" file into the BOOT directory.
7. Navigate to the BOOT directory, and update the "MyUtil.jar" file with the following:
          jar -uvfm ../MyUtil.jar boot-manifest.mf *.*
8. Your "MyUtil.jar" file should now be executable. Test it.

Comment: Yes, You will be able to include your files as well as dependent files into one executable jar. We have used this with autosys to excute timed jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single executable jar file in java.  This jar would have an application that does all the copying you've listed above.  But instead of copying from the desktop, it would copy directories that are included in the executable jar.  A jar is a zipped file type (in fact you can change the extension from jar to zip and examine the contents).

Your strategy will be to create a regular java application, package as an executable jar.  Include the directories you want to install as resources in the jar.  Check out the jar documentation for all java utility methods and classes to manipulate jars.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: One issue I am afraid about my .jar installer is that it contains an `import` that may not necessarily be available in every computer. `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` is something I had to download online, and dragged into my project. Do `.jar`s have the ability to package that as well?

Comment: Yes, technically you can package other libraries as jars inside your own jars.  However, legally, you just need to adhere to any copyright and license issues, particularly if you are going to release the software beyond your own private use.  For apache commons libraries, the license is available here: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0